# Hexidecimal color value to web-smart color

Tags: colors, color-depth

Anyone know of a tool which can convert a standard hexadecimal color value to the closest possible [web-smart](http://cloford.com/resources/colours/websmart1.htm) color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found what I was looking for http://www.html-color.net/ lets you enter in a hexidecimal value, and it will convert it to web-safe, web-smart, and unsafe colors!

Comment: the website is no longer exist

Answer (score 1):

Here's a site that does the conversion:
http://www.colortools.net/color_make_web-safe.html

Also I know that Photoshop has a checkbox in the color selector to display only the web safe.
http://graphicssoft.about.com/od/photoshop/ig/color/Web-Colors---Color-Libraries.htm

Comment: Web-safe is different from web-smart.  Web-smart has more colors than web-safe.